# Determine if the structure is a lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

> Given $X =$ {$1, 2, 3, 4$} and $S = $ {{1, 2}, {2}, ∅, {3, 4}, X} the
>   ordered set through the relation of inclusion $⊂$.
>
> (a) Draw the corresponding Hasse diagram of $S$.
>
> (b) Determine if $S$ is a lattice.

The hasse diagaram would start from the $∅$ element then connected to $1,2,3,4$
all connecting together to make $X$ with inter-connections between them if I am not wrong. But how to determine the lattice exactly?

Comment: Look at the axioms for a lattice and check them. Do all the necessary upper  bounds exist?

Comment: I think the upper bound will be unique and it will be $X$ if I am not wrong right?

Comment: If you look at the inclusion connections between the sets in $S$, you'll see that the Hasse diagram is that of the pentagon, $\mathbf N_5$, as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849736/no-group-has-mathbfn-5-as-its-lattice-of-subgroups), with $C=\{3,4\}$, $B=\{2\}$ and $A=\{1,2\}$. Of course I'm supposing that $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ or a bigger set.

Comment: @amrsa Shouldn't it be more like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg)?

Comment: How could it be like that if $|S|=5$? The diagram you have in that link has 8 nodes.

Comment: Oh so you placed the number of points according to the number of combiations? But I think it should be like an inter-connected network rather than a a rotating one as some of them don't share the same elements. If I am wrong please let me know.